# Google Groups API : Setting Google Groups spam moderation parameters

Tags: python, google-api, google-groups-api

I'm trying to change the "spamModerationLevel" parameter on all groups (~375 groups) on my company's google mail, and am struggling with the script i use.

I have managed to get the list of groups with a script inspired from [this doc](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/quickstart/python).
What I can't do, however, is update the required parameter.

```
body={'spamModerationLevel': 'ALLOW'}
editResult=service.groups().update(groupKey=*groupID*, body=body).execute()
```

This request doesn't return any error, but the moderation level isn't updated.
If I change the body of the request to something like

```
body={'description': 'test2'}
```

The request runs fine, and the group's description is updated.

Is there anything I missed? Using the API Explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/groupssettings/v1/groupsSettings.groups.update), I can change any parameter I want, so I assume I should be able to do so in a script.